# Generator expression in configure_file

Tags: cmake

We are porting some rather old code and of course we want to use generator expressions now.
The by `configure_file` generated .pc files now contain `-I$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>`.
The only hint about how to resolve generator expressions I found was to use

```
file(GENERATE
```

Of course this is executed during the configure step so the above expression is resolved to an empty string.

Edit:
here is an example
CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(test CXX)

add_library(foo SHARED main.cpp)

target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

# now later buried deep in some functions

get_property( _include_dirs TARGET foo PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES )

configure_file(config.in config.out @ONLY)
# content of config.out is "include = -I$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>"

file(GENERATE OUTPUT config.out2 INPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.out)
# content of config.out2 is "include = -I"
# most likely because the INSTALL_INTERFACE isn't used when the file is generated
```

config.in:

```
include = @_include_dirs@
```

and main.cpp is just empty.

Comment: Yes, `file(GENERATE)` is a proper way for configure a file with generator expressions in it. So, what is a **problem** (question)? Do you want to know how to use this command?

Comment: The problem is that `-I$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>` gets resolved to `-I` as mentioned before.

Comment: What is the reason for you needing to generate a .pc file during cmake's configure-process? Could you consider using add_custom_command to generate this file? Adding dependencies to such a command's target (even when using ExternalProject) is much easier.

Comment: The only reason I could imagine is the that there is another CMakeLists.txt added as a subdirectory which tries to read this file - so it must be generated before configuring. But the described targets in the .pc-file are not yet existing if they are built by cmake (or are they imported?). Strange situation... I'd recommend using targets and dependencies for that.

Comment: @PatrickB. Hm until now I only tried `install(CODE "file(GENERATE OUTPUT` with the initial outcome. The .pc is only needed for the installation later. I'll try a custom target, but in that code the dependency tracking might result in a problem.

Comment: If I were you I would not use `file(GENERATE ...)` at all but call a script with arguments (the generator expression) via `add_custom_command()`.

Comment: "I only tried `install(CODE "file(GENERATE OUTPUT)`" - No, this is completely wrong: the code executed as `install` (via `install(CODE)` or `install(SCRIPT)` doesn't see any target from your project. The command `file(GENERATE)` should be issued directly in your `CMakeLists.txt`. Then you may use `install(FILES)` for install resulted file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev then I end up in the initial situation....

Comment: But **what do you want to achive** by using `$<INSTALL_INTERFACE>` generator expression in your *file*? Reading [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) about this expression you may found, that it is primarily for **setting a target's property**. Using this expression outside of the target's property context has no sense.

Comment: I've added an example maybe you can understand my issue better now.

Answer (score 8):

As the CMake documentation states the [file (GENERATE ...)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html?highlight=generator%20expressions#generate) command can use generator expressions which are evaluated by the generator.

## Generate Files

You can let CMake generate files with custom code directly without the workaround of a [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html) command.

### Single-Config Generators

For single-config generators like *Makefiles* you can use:

```
file (GENERATE
    OUTPUT "config.out" 
    CONTENT "include = -I$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>"
)
```

As my CMake code has to work with both multi-config and single-config generators I did not test the code specifically.

### Single- And Multi-Config Generators

In general for all generators, one can use the following signature:

```
file (GENERATE
    OUTPUT "config_$<CONFIG>.out" 
    CONTENT "include = -I$<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>"
)
```

Due to the nature of the command in relation to multi-config generators like *Visual Studio* this will generate multiple files in your build folder for each build type specified in this variable [CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES.html#variable:CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES):

- config_Debug.out
- config_Release.out
- config_RelWithDebInfo.out
- ...
- config_< BUILD_TYPE >.out

If you do not specify unique filenames and CMake tries to generate the files it will stop the execution with an error.

## Use Generated Files

To use the previously generated files it depends on what you need. First of all the files will exist after the *configuration* stage.

### Single-Config Generators

To use a generated file in a single-config generator scenario with a constant name (e.g. config.out) there should be no additional work necessary.

### Single- And Multi-Config Generators

For multi-config generators it is slighty different. As you have to use [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) to access the appropriate file at build time. If you have a CMake instruction that supports generator expressions then you can just use the filename `config_$<CONFIG>.out`.

But if you need the file to be named exactly the same regardless of the build type (like config.out) it gets a little more tricky.

First you have to tell CMake that there should be a file named like `config.out` by using [add_custom_command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) and specifiying the *OUTPUT* parameter:

```
add_custom_command (
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} "-E" "copy_if_different" "config_$<CONFIG>.out" "config.out"
    VERBATIM
    PRE_BUILD
    DEPENDS  "config_$<CONFIG>.out"
    OUTPUT   "config.out"
    COMMENT  "creating config.out file ({event: PRE_BUILD}, {filename: config.out})"
)
```

CMake will create a file dependency internally and every time one references the filename `config.out` it will ensure that the *add_custom_command* gets executed.

But this will not work in every case as it depends on the further instructions which should use the file.

Depending on the commands you are using you can now specify the file `config.out` as input for some commands (like target_sources, ...) and CMake will detect on a file-dependency level that it has to ensure the existence of `config.out`.

If you want to generate a file which is not referenced on a file-dependency level (like versioninfo.txt) then you have to ensure that CMake executes the *add_custom_command* every time your build target gets executed via a target-dependency:

```
add_custom_target ("generate_config_out" DEPENDS "config.out")
add_dependencies ("MY_LIBRARY_TARGET" "generate_config_out")
```

Every time CMake builds the `MY_LIBRARY_TARGET` target it will previously build the `generate_config_out` target which in turn depends on the `config.out` that CMake will process on the file-dependency level.

Comment: Great answer. But what if the contents of the generated file is rather long? configure_file has the benefit of allowing me to put that into a separate file. But AFAICS file(GENERATE OUTPUT ... INPUT ...) doesn't replace ${...} variables, like configure_file does. Is there a solution that supports source files *and* generator expressions?

Comment: @DavidFaure In theory that should not be a problem. There is no artificial length limit of a string that I am aware of (probably 2G byte length). Thus you could read your whole source from a large file into a variable and use that as input for file-generate. A text file with contents in gigabyte sizes is quite rare and needs special treatment.
As for the variable replacement have a look into the documentation. CMake's `file(GENERATE ...)` command does support variable replacement as documented [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#configure).